Issue with adding new products to Facebook catalog for WhatsApp API
I'm having an issue with adding new products to my Facebook catalog that is integrated with the WhatsApp Business API. I have an existing catalog with products that are successfully being sent through the WhatsApp API. However, when I try to add new products, either manually or through a data feed, I receive the error message "None of the products provided could be sent. Please check your catalog."
i recently add commerce API to my app and it inactive but i can't remove it to check if this what cause the error.
Despite these efforts, the new products still cannot be sent through the WhatsApp API, while the existing/old products in the catalog work fine.
I've tried the following steps:

Manually adding new products to the catalog through Facebook Business Manager.

Creating a new product data feed and uploading it to the catalog.

Adding new products to both an existing catalog and creating a new catalog.

Waiting for 24 hours after adding the new products for the catalog to update.


Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any suggestions on troubleshooting steps I can take? I'm unsure if this is an issue with the product data, the catalog settings, or something else entirely.
